# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

forgive me. I have seen many topics with the same name but they did not help me.Probably everyone has a specific code.

```
    var app = angular.module('iop', []);
    // Set up the service factory to create our Items interface to the

    var obj={name:'sasha'}
    var obj2= {status: 'run'}

    app.factory('dataService', function(){
        return{

                text: ' js-frame?',
                author: 'Vani'
            }           
    })

    app.controller('QuestionController',['obj','$scope','obj2','dataService'
        function QuestionController(object,$scopes,object2,dataService){

            $scopes.data= object.name

         $scopes.text= object2.status +dataService.text

        }]
    )


<div ng-controller = "QuestionController">
Status :<p> {{data}}</p>
app: <p>{{text}}</p>
</div>
```

Error: 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function index.html:46
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]**

Comment: You are missing a comma after `'dataService'`

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. there is no html let alone line 46 in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two variables:

```
var obj={name:'sasha'}
var obj2= {status: 'run'}
```

Should be module values:

```
app.value("name", "sasha");
app.value("status", "run");
```

Then they can be injected into your controller like so:

```
 app.controller('QuestionController',['name','$scope','status','dataService',
            function QuestionController(name,$scope,status,dataService){
```

Also this line:

```
 app.controller('QuestionController',['obj','$scope','obj2','dataService'
        function QuestionController(object,$scope,object2,dataService){
```

Is missing a comma after **dataService**

```
app.controller('QuestionController',['obj','$scope','obj2','dataService',
         function QuestionController(object,$scope,object2,dataService){
```

You also misspelled **$scope** a few times. (Have **$scopes**)

Hopefully those corrections will help.

Comment: Works .Added app.value("obj", obj);
app.value("obj2", obj2);

Answer (score 3):

1. obj and obj2 are plain objects, you didn't register them as an angular service\provider\constant\anything, so they're not inject able.
2. Don't use minified version of angular, you'll receive better error messages that way.